# Error while deploying to Firebase from Travis CI

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, travis-ci, firebase-cli

I am getting the error "Error: Server Error. certificate has expired" while deploying to firebase from Travis

Updating the CLI version does not help.

firebase-tools@7.12.0 is the updated CLI version and I still get the error .

Kindly help! Thanks!

Comment: can anyone pls help on this?

Comment: Same issue.. :( any luck in finding the solution?